# Typescript indexed access in which index is queried from another property of the same interface

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

An example demonstrates my question better than words:

```
interface X {
    a: number,
    b: string
}

interface KeyValue<T> {
    key: keyof T,
    value: T[this['key']]
}

const keyValue: KeyValue<X> = {
    key: 'a',
    value: 'Error! this should be a number'
};
```

I want the type of `value` to be based on value of `key`. I mean if `key` is **a**, then I need the type of `value` to be the same as type of `X[a]`, which is `number`. But currently, the type of `value` is `string | number` which is the union type of all value types in `X`.

Can I achieve this with current typescript features?

Comment: Guessing `Y` should have properties `x` and `y`

Comment: You could define the key type as generic parameter. I wonder what's the real use case?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it directly you need an extra type parameter

```
interface X {
    a: number,
    b: string
}

interface KeyValue<T, K extends keyof T> {
    key: K,
    value: T[this['key']] // or T[K]
}

const keyValue: KeyValue<X, 'a'> = {
    key: 'a',
    value: 0
};
```

To avoid typing the name of the property twice you can use a function to help with the creation. You need a fi function that returns a function as Typescript does not allow partial type argument inference yet

```
function newY<T>() {
    return function <K extends keyof T>(p: Y<T, K>) {
        return p;
    }
}

let xx = newY<X>()({ key: 'a', value:0})
```